# How do I print the input of InputDialog into the dialog itself?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

**I have this app:**

[image]

**I want this:**

[image]

**My problems:**

1. I'm not sure how to implement that
2. The main window pops up when I'm done with the input dialog

**What I have so far:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'My First PyQt5 Window'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.getText()

        self.show()

    def getText(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Get text", "Your name:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if ok and text != '':
            print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the QInputDialog but if you use the static method getText() it is complicated, instead you must create the QInputDIalog as an instance and then add the QLabel with the necessary connections:

```
def getText(self):

    dialog = QInputDialog(self)
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Get text")
    dialog.setLabelText("Your name:")
    dialog.setTextValue("")
    dialog.setTextEchoMode(QLineEdit.Normal)
    dialog.show()
    label = QLabel()

    def on_text_changed(text):
        label.setText("you printed {}".format(text))

    le = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit)
    le.textEdited.connect(on_text_changed)
    on_text_changed(le.text())
    dialog.layout().insertWidget(2, label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    ret = dialog.exec_()
    ok = bool(ret)
    text = dialog.textValue() if ret else ""
    if ok:
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (e.g. in your `__init__()`):

```
  self.label = QLabel('Text will be shown here')

  self.button = QPushButton('Change text')
  self.button.clicked.connect(self.getText)
  
  hl = QHBoxLayout(self)
  self.setLayout(hl)
  hl.addWidget(self.label)
  hl.addWidget(self.button)
```

And in the event handler:

```
def getText(self):
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(...)
    if ok and text != '': self.label.setText(text)
```

Comment: That looks promising but I get `AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'label'` which is weird because `self.label` is clearly defined in the constructor

Comment: You may be accessing 'label', before it is declared  
(e.g. if you added the code after initUI(),  
and are still calling self.getText() in initUI()).  
Btw, in initUI(), do not call self.getText().  
It will get called as a result of button-clicked events.